# SATA as transport medium for external device

Tags: usb, sata

I have free sata connector in my laptop and I've wondered if is there any option to use SATA as some kind of data transmission, like USB. Will i need to write my own drivers? 
Bottom line is: i want to design a device that is connected to laptop in optical bay. Any ideas?

Comment: I strongly believe the SATA controller is hardcoded by the BIOS... Yet you might try to disguise your device as a SATA HDD.

Comment: Eugene is correct. Think about UEFI... how do you think an operating system loads up every time you turn on your computer?

Comment: I thought about it. Do you think it will be possible to make it that, when i write TO the disk it will be then seen by my device as command/data incomming or sth?

Comment: @MateuszKowalik Grab SATA protocol specification and see if it makes sense for your device to implement it.

Comment: One of those questions where if you have to ask, you can't do it.

Comment: As i surfed trough the web, the problem that might be hard to overcome, is that driver chips for HDD are not possible to get for non milion dollar company.

Comment: Rip them off recycled drives.

Answer (score 1):

There are low cost readily available IDE/PATA to SATA convertors such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0185LC04Y). 
[image]

The PATA interface is straightforward and very well [documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA).

All the versions I've seen will support the PIO and UDMA modes, and clock speeds are quite reasonable if you stay at or below UDMA(2) -- 33 MB/s. 
You can make a very simple interface using the PIO modes, this will give you only a maximum of 16.7 MB/s but it's very easy to emulate a disk drive in these modes directly from an MCU.

[This](http://www.interfacebus.com/IDE_HardDrive_Interface_Bus_Description.html) might be a good starting point for you.